# ko.mapping observableArray always trigger subscription

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin, ko.observablearray

I am working with ko.mapping plugin in order to map data coming from an ajax request.
Setting the key i expect that subscription is not triggered in this case but it's always raised; i can't understand why. Thx in advance.

```
var arraySource = [{ Prop: 1, Prop2: 1 }, { Prop: 2, Prop2: 2 }];
var mappedArray = ko.observableArray([]);
mappedArray.subscribe(function (data) {
    console.log(data);
});
window.setInterval(function () {
    ko.mapping.fromJS(arraySource, {
        key: function (data) {
            return data.Prop;
        }
    }, mappedArray);
}, 3000);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Andrew Walters suggested the subscription will always be triggered, because the entire array is overwritten with the new content. 
I found a way to recognoze what really changed by reading the knockout release 3  : http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2013/10/08/knockout-3-0-release-candidate-available/

```
var myArray = ko.observableArray(["Alpha", "Beta", "Gamma"]);

myArray.subscribe(function(changes) {
    // For this example, we'll just print out the change info
    console.log(changes);
}, null, "arrayChange");
```

inside the subscription it's possible to get the added, deleted and retained elements in a very simple way !

Answer (score 1):

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/xvzAj/

Based on the comment in the docs it sounds like passing the third parameter to `.fromJS` will overwrite the properties of the array which would trigger the notification.

> ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, someObject); // overwrites properties on
>   someObject

Source: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html

In the knockout.mapping.js ln 627, the array contents are replaced which is triggering the subscription notification.

```
mappedRootObject(newContents);
```

https://github.com/SteveSanderson/knockout.mapping/blob/master/build/output/knockout.mapping-latest.debug.js

Comment: maybe you are right, but subscriptions on observableArrays are triggered only when an object is added or removed, not when its properties change ...

Comment: You'd have to step through the mapping code to verify but it could be replacing the whole array, I'm not sure. If the third param is removed, notifications aren't triggered anymore. http://jsfiddle.net/xvzAj/1/

Comment: Of course it is not triggered, because the mappedArray is not filled at all.

Comment: I've updated my answer with the line from mapping.js which is triggering the subscription notification. Hopefully it will be more clear now.

Comment: Yes, now i got what you mean, thx, but it not depends by the provieded (or not) third parameters. It seems there are no way to map an Array at Root level: it'll always replace the whole array.